# Elden Ring - PS4. Games does not start

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, elden-ring

I finally found a game that I wouls like to play, but I can't, for reasons.
I own fairly old PS4 (not pro version) almost 6 years. It worked and still works just fine, but it does not for the Elden Ring.

I always buy games via PSN (I am a Plus Platinum Member), and I did the same with the Elden Ring.
After waiting some time for it to install, and kind of being excited about the game, I got the nasty surprise:

**CE-34224-5**

I have tried many things that I was able to find on the internet, but nothing helped. Here are the things I have tried:

1. Quick Initialisation
2. Full Initialisation (took over 2 hours)
3. Reinstall Firmware in Safe Mode (Went well)
4. Changed the DNS settings to my internet connection (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)
5. Used completely different Internet (Cell Phone Internet)
6. Rebuilt the Database (After every initialization)
7. Reinstalled the game after every Initialization
8. Contacted support (They told me to check the Firmware)
9. My PS account is set as primary and only one

I do not have any ideas left. Other games do work (the latest AAA titles, which are huge as well). Netflow works... everything else works, except the Elden Ring.
Usually, I would just give up, but this game has George R. R. Martin's touch to it, and it is a masterpiece.

Comment: Just for the record, if you want to connect Google's public DNS service, it is 8.8.8.8 (primary) and *8.8.4.4* (secondary), not 8.4.4.8. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS), in case you need it)

Comment: Thank you for your notice. I used the correct one but made a typo in the post. I will fix it now.

Comment: I don't get it. This morning I clicked on the game icon, and it started (worked perfectly). I played for some time and turned it off.  Sometime later, I tried to start it again, and the same thing all over again. This can't be a hardware issue, this is a game issue... I am lost here :(

Comment: I shut it down completely. Let it rest for an hour or so, and it started again. This reminds me of Commodore and ZX Spectrum's good old days when you were not sure whether the game wills start or not.

Comment: That sounds like hardware issue.

Comment: I can start ot like this anytime now. Very strange, but it works.